# Why does my transaction not start with full gas?

Tags: gas, evm

Im trying to optimize the gas costs of my smart contract, and noticed a large chunk called "Initial gas" in the tenderly debugger. Upon digging further, I confirmed that the function call does indeed not start with full gas. Here is the tenderly report of the first line in my contract:

```
{
  "[FUNCTION]":"createVault"
  "[OPCODE]":"JUMPDEST"
  "contract":{...}
  "caller":{...}
  "input":{...}
  "output":{}
  "gas":{
  "gas_left":2977628
  "gas_used":15005
  "total_gas_used":22372
}
```

Does anyone what the 22372 gas are spent on?

Comment: Are you asking why some gas is already spent even when entering the first function of the contract? That's because the EVM doesn't know "functions" and at the beginning of the contract, it does some logic to load the input data and jump to the assembly code where the compilation of your function resides. I have no clue how much gas that would cost. Thousands of gas sounds a bit high to me, but maybe it isn't.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Hi, thanks for the reply! Yes thats what I was asking. That sounds logical, but its a lot of gas which seems a bit strange to me. On competitors Ive even seen consumptions of up to 70k. Do you know any resource where I could look up what the EVM is doing there?

Comment: I don't have actual resources. I got this knowledge in the past from chatgpt-4 and verified it by inspecting the beginning assembly code of actual contracts.